# Python - efficient way to write to a file text?

Tags: python

I'm writing to a text file but it's not work properly as I expected.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/usr/lib/env python
import re

file = open("address.txt","r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
content = content.split('LAN ')[1:]
dic = {}
for lan in content:
    dic[int(lan[0])] = lan[1:] 



def address(lan_index):
    address = re.findall('address\s(.*?)\s',dic[lan_index] )
    if len(address) > 0:
        print 'LAN', lan_index, ":", address[0]
    else:
        print 'No Address Found!'
    return address[0]


ad1 = str(address(1))
new_ad = ad1
var1 = 'ad1'


filedata = None
with open('address.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
  
filedata = filedata.replace(ad1 , var1)

with open('address.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

here's my text file:

```
#line addresses LAN 1
        address 192.168.6.6
        network 192.168.6.6
```

my problem is when I want to replace `ad1` for `var1` it wont replace only my `address` only it will replace `network` as well as they have the same IP.

My output is something like this:

> address ad1
>
> network ad1

Is there an efficient and possible way to avoid this and get something like this:

> address ad1
>
> network 192.168.6.6

I would be very grateful if that's possible. **Thank you**

Comment: Read the file by lines? Only replace the line if contains address, not  network?

Comment: @cricket_007 not a bad idea.. regex is actually often slower than simple string operations if only simple matches are needed. the benefit of regex is flexibility and complicated patterns, not speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your address are being replaced because `filedata.replace(ad1 , var1)` is greedy. You can limit it by giving it the optional third argument: `filedata.replace(ad1 , var1, 1)` telling it to make at most `1` replacements, or you could expand your capture group: `'(address\s.*?)\s'` to include "address", and make `var1 = "address ad1"` so that `filedata.replace` only finds the lines that have "address" in them